# Tesla Backup Switch not considered first disconnect?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I recently had Tesla install PV and a PowerWall battery. They installed a [Backup Switch](https://www.tesla.com/support/energy/powerwall/learn/tesla-backup-switch)
as a means to disconnect from the grid and power my house with the solar and battery. In the picture below you can see the PSE&G meter as well as the Backup Switch (which is in its own meter pan since PSE&G doesn't permit it behind theirs). My main panel is inside, and they changed the feeder from the original meter to the Backup Switch. They used a supply-side tap in my main (100A) panel to connect the solar+battery. My main panel had neutral and grounds bonded and they didn't change anything about that. From what I can tell there is no ground connection to either of the two meter pans outside.

I'm planning to upgrade my service and indoor panel to 200A.

My question is whether it is correct that the main panel still has neutrals and grounds bonded, since I would the Backup Switch would be considered the first means of disconnect. I could see that this is not the case if they mount it directly behind the meter, but shouldn't the ground and neutral bonding happen in that second meter pan?

I'm on the 2017 NEC code, and have applied for a permit for my main panel and service upgrade, and I'm not required to have an exterior disconnect under the New Jersey Rehab code, according to my local inspector.

The Tesla install has not been inspected yet, but as I'm planning my panel replacement, I want to make sure I won't be surprised about having to move the ground and neutral bonding to outside.
[image: Meter pan and backup switch]
[image: Existing panel]
[image]

Comment: > since I would think the Backup Switch would be considered the first means of disconnect Interesting theory. Let me ask you a couple of questions, since the photo is too fuzzy to see for sure. First, where is the manual actuating handle that allows you to physically operate the Tesla Backup Switch? Some obvious lever or toggle plainly marked "On/Off". *It would need to have that in order to be a service disconnect.* Also, does the Tesla Backup Switch have a label that says "Not A Service Disconnect"? Could it be caused to have such a label? Because that would settle the question.

Comment: I added a close-up picture that shows the label on the bottom: "Manual override not to be used unless directed by Tesla". That seems to not meet the requirements for a Service Disconnect, so I should be fine to keep grounds and neutrals bonded in my new panel.